# USB Mouse to Bluetooth Mouse?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

Is it possibe to turn a wireless usb mouse into a bluetooth mouse so I can use it on my phone and tablet? I want to do this because my computer's usb ports are all taken and my PC supports bluetooth. If there is any way to do this, please tell me. The mouse I want to do this with is a Logitech M317.

Comment: Bluetooth mouse $15 including shipping: https://www.amazon.com/JETech-Bluetooth-Wireless-Android-12-month/dp/B01B1PZ4HG/ref=pd_sim_sbs_147_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=41LoMiian9L&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&psc=1&refRID=D762TTDZ1Z1B85RVM85V.  Something tells me you can't re-engineer a wireless USB mouse for $15.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, practically: no.

You can either rebuild part of the hardware in the mouse to speak bluetooth,
or buy a bluetooth mouse and transplant its hardware,
or add something like a rpi, a USB BT interface and a battery pack in the mouse.

All three are less practical than just buying a bluetooth mouse.

Comment: And how exactly do you suggest to "rebuild part of the hardware in the mouse" to change the Logitech proprietary 2.4GHz protocol into Bluetooth protocol?

Comment: It doesn't. You would need to transplant the other mouses BT parts (both the in mouse sender and the receiver to plug into the computer) and match up all the right buttons and possible the scroll wheel. It is insensible to do unless you really want this and have a specially formed mouse which is not available with BT. For most people this will not be the case.

Comment: Why would you want to "transplant" parts of a ready-to-go Bluetooth mouse into M317 mouse when the BT mouse already solves the problem of OP? For the sake of sport? Why do you advise to re-build a nano-receiver if the BT is already inside the laptop?

Comment: ` unless you really want this and have a specially formed mouse`

Comment: @AliChen Not sure what you are trying to say. The two responses from two people, have stated that it is indeed possible to do which answers the OP's question if it was or not. Regardless of how complex it would be to do so, that is not what was asked. Secondly Both responses stated that it is complex too, therefore, its not a practical solution even though it is a solution still. To guide someone on how to go about it, would most likely be outside the scope of this community as well and very complex to detail the steps required as well.

Comment: @Frostalf: I am saying that your answers are outrageously disconnected from reality. The fact that BT mice do exist already answers the theoretical possibility. But it does not mean that any arbitrary person can make a BT mouse, especially given OTP hardware at hand. Your second answer indicates how far you are disconnected from complexity of the task, you completely missed the horrible complexity of logical protocol itself, recoveries, etc. The other advice to cut out internals of BT mouse with ALL electronics (and plastic?) and put it into M317 must be a mockery.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it is possible. How feasible is it would be the question, and it wouldn't be practical. The mouse you listed has its own reciever for being wireless meaning it won't work over bluetooth unless you modify the mouse's hardware, there are however mice that are made to work using bluetooth. The Logitech V270 or the Logitech M557 are both mouses that will work over bluetooth.

Comment: Same question for @Frostalf: how exactly do you suggest to "modify the mouse's hardware" to change the Logitech proprietary 2.4GHz protocol into Bluetooth protocol?

Comment: @AliChen I have responded to your comment via an answer below as it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Logitech M317 mouse uses the nRF31512 radio from Nordic Semiconductors, which, I believe, is a OEM version and a part of Nordic's nRF24 family.

The nRF31512 is actually a SoC (System-On-Silicon) based on 8051 microprocessor, with embedded radio, encryption accelerator, and a bunch of other interfaces, including a serial link to a separate optical chip (that tracks the mouse position/movement). Yes, this radio operates in 2.4GHz band. More, Nordic uses very similar chips to provide Bluetooth interfaces. However it does not mean whatsoever that some DIY techie can program the chip to follow Bluetooth protocol.

Of course, one can get a development kit from Nordic, buy a Keil compiler license, and even have an example code for Bluetooth. However, the mouse has a bunch of other things to control, pushbuttons, wheel, power management, service the optical sensor, so it is highly unlikely that one can get a full mouse package. Provided that OP is an expert in embedded programming, it likely will take few man-years to develop.

Lastly, the mass-produced mice likely would use an OTP (One-Time_Programmable) version of SoC, so there will be no way to re-program the code in off-the-shelf mouse.

In summary, the answer to OP question is **hell NO**, there is no way to re-use the Logitech M317 mouse to make it as a Bluetooth device.

Comment: While I understand what you are saying, for clarity purposes, Hennes and myself responded the way we did because, technically yes you could modify it to make it do what you want. Whether that is use your own software for it or modify the existing software. Again, its just not feasible or practical. And yes it does mean some person given they have the knowledge of how to access the chips can just change the software to make it do what you want it to do, how long it takes depends how much info you have about the hardware and resources about said hardware at your disposal.

Comment: Also can even go from reprogramming the entire mouse to purely use your own software, or you can attempt to modify the existing software in place if you know how to do a bit of reverse engineering or if its open source

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Chen
Couldn't fit the response in a comment.

Well, without getting too technical, the transmitor, transmits on the 2.4Ghz frequency to the reciever, the reciever is actively listening for its messages on this band. Bluetooth uses this same band. Wifi and Bluetooth both occupy the 2.4Ghz Band that is 83MHz wide. Bluetooth uses Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum between 79 1 MHz wide channels. Where as Wifi uses Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum on 1 channel that is 22 MHz wide allowing 11 overlapping channels. Knowing that, all one would really need to do, is change how the transmitor transmits and the reciever, recieves. Since both devices have electronic boards you can access them given you know how and change the firmware as necessary. I am not claiming this is easy to do either as in my previous answer I already stated its not practical lol.

Additional Response to @Ali Chen from the comments below

You might be able to find a tutorial on how to use JTAG on a router board to do a physical flash of the rom. However, this concept is essentially the same for every electronic board, the only difference is whether you could modify the firmware from the rom natively without additional hardware or if you need additional hardware, where you would need to soder the your connection on the board. You might need a program that could read/write raw data as well or communicate with the board in some fashion via this sodered port. So its by no means easy. Really have to know electronic egineering lol.

Also the chips on most electronic boards are not necessarily proprietary more or less the firmware/software in the rom or rom's is which is what makes everything work on the electronic board.

Comment: the chips on most electronic boards are not necessarily proprietary more or less the firmware/software in the rom or rom's is which is what makes everything work on the electronic board.

Comment: You said, "really have to know electronic engineering". I could not agree more

Comment: @Frostalf you should merge this into your other answer.